# Laravel Eloquent Save Method - Variable Length

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm really having a weird issue on using laravel eloquent save function.

Here's my model:

```
use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole {
  protected $fillable = array('name', 'description', 'updated_at');
}
```

Controller:

```
class RoleController extends \BaseController {
  public function store()
  { 
     $data = Input::all();
     //validation here
     $field = new Role($data);
     $field->save(); 

  } 
}
```

Post data:

```
Array
(
 [_token] => ptQQms6jzn7BgFKq4A4kEfGxifKqaRZwGHlYMqVH
 [name] => abc 
 [description] = > some role description    
)
```

My problem is in the 'name' variable, the $field->save(); is the not working if the variable length is less than 4 characters and I didn't set any rules for the variable length.

for example:

```
[name] => abc;  //$field->save() not working, and not returning errors
[name] => abcd; //works perfectly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
$field = new Role($data);
$field->save();
```

Either you do:

```
$field = new Field;
$field->name = $data['name'];
$field->save();
```

or

```
Role::create([
  'name' => $data['name'],
]);
```

Comment: But he said it's working perfectly in one of the cases... So maybe you can? I mean I like you syntax better, but "can't" is a pretty absolute word.

Comment: My bad then @TimLewis

Comment: hi guys, thank you for the response, i already figure out the reason why its not saving if the variable is less than 4 characters. The issue is in my model, the  "  extends EntrustRole ". Entrust Class has its own validation.